# Facebookclient Object doesn't contain the "Get" method yet all examples do. WP7

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I am writing a test app which will simply ask the user to login to facebook via a webbrowser control. Then on the Navigated event a message box will appear relaying the user name of the user. The example I have been following uses a a FacebookClient.Get() method and so do many other examples on the net. My problem is that the FacebookClient doesn't even contain a Get().

I am using C#4.0, and I referenced the Facebook C# SDK from NuGet.

```
private void wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult result;
        if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Uri, out result))
        {
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                var accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
                var fb = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);

                var _result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me");
                var name = (string)_result["name"];

                MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
            }
            else
            {
                var errorDescription = result.ErrorDescription;
                var errorReason = result.ErrorReason;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version? I see a Get function in the source code: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3923a193ca45#Source%2fFacebook%2fFacebookClient.cs

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548576/fb-get-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook C# SDK isn't really optimised for WP7, I recommend using the facebook API without going through the sdk c#